# Compare difference of two lists, .Except() algorithm to replace LINQ

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-3.0

I used to use `.Except()` to compare the difference of two List in C# by using LINQ like following.

```
List<string> APromotionProduct= GetAPromotionProduct(PrdA);
List<string> BPromotionProduct = GetBPromotionProduct<string>(PrdB);
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
tempList = PromotionProduct.Except(XMLPromotionProduct).ToList();
```

However, my company is not using LINQ, we are on .NET 3.
Therefore I can't use `Enumerable.Except`. How can I achieve the same purpose
or how can I write the algorithm for `.Except()`.

Comment: What IDE you're using is irrelevant...

Comment: What version of the .NET framework your company is using? Why you can't use one >= 3.5?

Comment: "how can I write the algorithm for .Except()." Think about it... in 2 loops you would compare one list with another and extract only the elements that are not present in the other.

Comment: If you can't think of a loop yourself, try checking the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/64071682ee3bf309.html)

Comment: @ Equalsk  My company in house IDE

Comment: @TimSchmelter My company in house IDE, can't access library

Comment: Can't access what library? It's part of the .NET Framework. Is your application C# or not? Are you asking to rewrite Except in another language or something?

Comment: @ChanYoongHon: it has nothing to do with the IDE used. What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: @Equalsk My application is C# with .Net Version 3.0. My company IDE can't use LINQ at all.

Comment: Right, now we've got it. That is a key piece of information, put it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use LINQ for whatever reason, this is the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8):

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

So you could use a `HashSet<string>`(ok, still .NET 3.5 needed):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptNoLinq<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) 
{
    HashSet<TSource> set = new HashSet<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var exceptItems = PromotionProduct.ExceptNoLinq(XMLPromotionProduct);
List<string> resultList = new List<string>(exceptItems);
```

If you are even on .NET 2:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptDotNet2<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<TSource, bool>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in second) dict.Add(element, true);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(element))
        {
            dict.Add(element, true);
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really help me. LINQ make people lazy to think like me.

Comment: @ChanYoongHon: If you are on .NET3 you should be able to use the last dictionary approach.

Comment: Schemelter Accepted

Answer (score 1):

Except() is an extension method from System.Linq. If you can refer this namespace in your file then you should be able to use it. This doesn't require a Visual studio. As long as you have access to the compiler you can compile and run your code.